# How fill NA/Null for categorical Varibles in python using fillna() function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

I Have one data set which contains some categorical variables and they have some missing(NA/Null). I Want to fill these NA/Nulls with Mode of that Column.
I tired Following thing but This didn't work

```
MD=Data['Gender'].mode()
Data['Gender'].fillna(value=MD,inplace=True)


MD=Data['Married'].mode()
Data['Married'].fillna(value=MD,inplace=True)

MD=Data['Dependents'].mode()
Data['Dependents'].fillna(value=MD,inplace=True)

MD=Data['Self_Employed'].mode()
Data['Self_Employed'].fillna(value=MD,inplace=True)

MD=Data['Credit_History'].mode()
Data['Credit_History'].fillna(value=MD,inplace=True)

Gender                26
Married                6
Dependents            30
Education              0
Self_Employed         64
ApplicantIncome        0
CoapplicantIncome      0
LoanAmount             0
Loan_Amount_Term       0
Credit_History       100
Property_Area          0
Loan_Status            0
```

Still its Showing missing values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
Data['Married'].fillna(Data['Married'].mode(), inplace=True)
```

Or Try this:

```
Data['Married'].fillna(Data['Married'].value_counts().index[0], inplace=True)
```

Ensure that dtype of your categorical variables is object or category.

Comment: This Did work .NA Values are Still there After Executing this code.
And Data Types are also objects.

Comment: One thing I tried, I work when you pass value directly but Doesn't work when varible is passed. 
Data['Gender'].fillna(value='Male',inplace=True)

Comment: @HardCoder it worked on my side. Nevermind, added another method. It should work.

Comment: Data['Married'].fillna(Data['Married'].value_counts().index[0], inplace=True)
this worked.
Thanks Manish Saraswat

Comment: Is there a way to do it for multiple columns? I can fill NA for multiple numerical columns by using ```df.fillna(df.median()[num_cols], inplace=True)``` yet I can not find similar one-liner for categorical columns. Neither ```df.fillna(df.mode()[categorical_cols], inplace=True)``` nor ```df.fillna[categorical_cols](df.mode()[categorical_cols], inplace=True)``` works...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Data['Married'].fillna(Data['Married'].mode()[0], inplace=True)
```